# Automatically constrain string size using initialization in VHDL

Tags: string, vhdl, declare

I'm working with VHDL, and I'm wondering if there is any way to constrain the string size when declaring it, using initialization. For example, we declare a string as follow:

```
variable sequence : string(1 to 20) := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";
```

I would like to know if there is any way to do something like:

```
variable sequence : string := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";
```

Of course, second line isn't valid, because interpreter says:

```
[VRFC 10-1547] variable cannot be unconstrained
```

Comment: Once VHDL 2019 gets some support, then the second way will be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants don't have to be constrained, so you could do this:

```
constant Csequence : string := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";
variable Vsequence : string(Csequence'range) := Csequence;
```

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/r3wK

```
entity E is
end entity E;

architecture A of E is
begin
  process
    constant Csequence : string := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";
    variable Vsequence : string(Csequence'range) := Csequence;
  begin
  wait;
  end process;
  
end architecture A;
```

Comment: That's a nice trick! Thank you. I hope VHDL interpreters updates to 2019. Until that, I'll use your trick.

Comment: There's also a function to return the length of the string literal. `variable sequence:  string (1 to strlen("AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC")) := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";`

Comment: You can use the function to produce a range stored in a subtype declaration: `subtype gac is string (1 to strlen("AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC")); variable sequence: string (gac'range) := "AGTAACCAATTCGCATTCGC";` (This counts on the string literal being static).